# Magento2 if I am selling a paid extension then do we need a private repository?

Tags: magento2, extensions

I am new to uploading an extension on Marketplace & selling it, I would like to know if I am selling a paid extension then do we need a private repository of packagelist.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are uploading extension on Magento Marketplace, then the extension will be uploaded on the repo of Magento 2. You do not need any additional repository.

Comment: How extension will be available using composer ?

Comment: It will be uploaded Repo of Magento 2 (https://repo.magento.com/)

Comment: so, just uploading extension in developer marketplace will make it available in magento repo as well as a composer link too ? once its passed from magento qa ?

Comment: Yes they take care of hosting it in their repo and making it accessible via composer